# making train set when we have a group in data set

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cross-validation

I want to make a train set but one of the my columns is group (household) and second column persons in each household. Now if I want to make a train set it must be contain all members of a household. a sample of my data set is like this:

```
 household    person     
     1           1
     1           1
     1           2
     2           1
     2           2
     2           2
     2           3
```

Now if one of first 3 rows is in train data all 3 rows must be. so in this small sample  there is 2 possibility for train data

1

```
 household    person     
     1           1
     1           1
     1           2
```

or

```
     household    person    
     2           1
     2           2
     2           2
     2           3
```

Comment: `trainthousehold <- sample(unique(x$household), size=1)` should give you a uniform distribution chance of sampling by household. You can make your train/test from here with `x[x$household %in% trainhousehold,]` and `x[!x$household %in% trainhousehold,]`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` verbs.

```r
# create toy data
df <- data.frame(house=sample(c(1:1000),100,T),
                 person=sample(c(1:4),1000,T))

# remove duplicate house-person pairs from toy data
df <- df %>% group_by(house,person) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup() #%>% count(house)

# sample 80% of households for training data
train <- df %>% distinct(house) %>% sample_frac(0.8) %>% left_join(.,df)
# and make remaining 20% test data
test <- df %>% filter(!(house %in% train$house))

# sanity check -- make sure houses are not in both datasets
test$house %in% train$house
train$house %in% test$house
```

Comment: what is c(1:4) and c(1:1000)?